# Check if in cell Today's date then continue

Tags: google-apps-script

I found a script on the Internet and am trying to alter it a little to fit my needs. But stumbled upon a problem. The script takes a list of bookmarks from the drop down menu and if you write OK in the next cell, then it transfers the line to the selected bookmark. I want to confirm today's date.

Copy of the sheet. Also here some diffeent.

var actionCol = 7;
var nameCol = 6;

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P9avWP8i5Z4KA4zt3EoUZNbgMKeXwnOYKsgCG2_vSLE/edit?usp=sharing

```
/**
 * Moves row of data to another spreadsheet based on criteria in column 6 to sheet with same name as the value in column 4.
*/
 
function onEdit(e) {
  // see Sheet event objects docs
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  
  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
  var actionCol = 10;
  var nameCol = 9;
 
  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
   
  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
   
  // if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
  if (e.value == "ok" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      // or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `But stumbled upon a problem.` Can you be more specific? Are you getting any error? How's the actual outcome differing from the one you expect? Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, indicating this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to cut & paste the edited row if:

1. The edited column is `G`, and the value is a Date corresponding to today.
2. The corresponding name in column `F` refers to the name of an existing sheet.

In order to check that the two dates correspond to the same day, you can compare the values returned by [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), as in this function (credits to [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855221)):

```
function sameDay(d1, d2) {
  return d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
         d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
         d1.getDate() === d2.getDate();
}
```

Then, you can call this in your main function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var value = r.getValue();
  var actionCol = 7;
  var nameCol = 6;
  var rowIndex = r.getRow();
  var colIndex = r.getColumn();
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn();
  if (value instanceof Date && colIndex == actionCol) {
    var today = new Date();
    if (sameDay(value, today)) {
      var targetSheetName = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
      if (targetSheet) {
        var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
        var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1);
        sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
        s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: now the function works in such a way that if the tab is selected in the "F" column and the "G" column was changed to "ok" then the line is transferred.

I want to change so that for the place "ok" in the column "G" the date is displayed and if it is today's date, then copying occurs.

Logically, I understand how everything goes, but here I have to write wild problems myself. not given: D

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @UnrealHA The script is already checking if it's today's date, even if the `ok` is not changing to a date. Do you mean you want the date in `C` to get copied to `G`, then compare the date to today's date, and then, if it matches, move the row to the destination sheet?

Comment: instead of "OK" write date, and then check if the date today then copy.

Comment: @UnrealHA So you want to copy the data if today's date is written to `G`, disregarding `C`. I edited my answer, including the code snippet, in order to do this. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @UnrealHA `Not work` can you please be more precise? Are you getting any error? I have tested this before posting, it works. Have you copied the script as it is, including the function `sameDay`?

Comment: @UnrealHA Make sure that (1) `sameDay` is copied to your script (you haven't copied it to the sample you provided), (2) you write a valid date, with the valid format according to your spreadsheet settings (in your case you should write `11/18/2020` I think) - if you mix up days and months, you might not get a valid date, since a year does not have an 18th month!, and (3) column `F` contains a valid sheet name **before** adding the date to `G`.

Comment: I understood where my problem was. Thank you so much. Everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var actionCol = 10;
  var nameCol = 9;
  var rowIndex = r.rowStart;
  var colIndex = r.columnStart;
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
  const dt=new Date(e.range.offset(0,n));//you add the column offset 
  const dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const td=new Date();
  const tdv=new Date(td.getFullYear(),td.getMonth(),td.getDate()).valueOf();
  if (e.value == "ok" && colIndex == actionCol && dtv==tdv) {
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    var tSh = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
    if (tSh) { 
      var targetRange = tSh.getRange(tSh.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    }
  }
}
```