Moving script dosen't get last row in Col B
Here is what the script does:
It move rows on 3 different tabs when the date in the row is equal todays date. That part is working fine.
The part I'm trying to fix is that when a row gets moved to main sheet called "pipe" it will paste to next available row in Col A.
I want it to paste the row in the next available row in Col B instead.
The script that is moving all the rows to my main sheet is called "MoveAll" and the script that I'm trying to fix the move to Col B is called "Getlastrow_"
I have tried to make the "MoveAll" script call the "Getlastrow_" function in the last lines of the script here:
targetSh.appendRow(sheetData[i]);
targetSh.getRange(getLastRow_(targetSh, 2),+1,2,1).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
sourceSh.deleteRow(i+1);
But it doesn't seem to work.
So any ideas would be very appreciated.
Here is a link to my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Vkd8_T4uzzS18E6VfA332YLfen-G5Oe0g_L5xiKsmk/edit?usp=sharing
Here is my script:
function MoveAll() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSh = ss.getSheetByName("Pipe");
  var sheets = ["Resting","Bokad","Återkomster"], sourceSh,dateCell;
  var dateCol = [];
  dateCol["Resting"] = 20;
  dateCol["Bokad"] = 15;
  dateCol["Återkomster"] = 14; 
  for (var sheetName of sheets)
  {
    sourceSh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheetData = sourceSh.getDataRange().getValues();

    // Check all values from your "Flight Schedule" sheet
    for(i = sheetData.length-1; i>= 0; i--){
      // Check if the value is a valid date
      dateCell = sheetData[i][dateCol[sheetName]-1];
      if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
        const today = new Date();
        const test = new Date(dateCell);
        // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
        if(test <= today){
          
          targetSh.appendRow(sheetData[i]);
          targetSh.getRange(getLastRow_(targetSh, 2),+1,2,1).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
          sourceSh.deleteRow(i+1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

and here is the function
function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 4 April 2021
  const values = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}

I have tried to follow instructions that I have gotten before regarding this matter but without sucess

sheet is private. also whats your desired output...

@player0 Sry about that and I tried to be more specific this time. Any help is greatly appreciated

That part is working fine. The part I'm trying to fix is I am confused. 1)  if(test <= today){ This tests whether the date is LESS THAN today; so it is NOT working fine. 2) paste the row in the next available row in Col B instead. This IS working already. 3) Would you please edit your spreadsheet to include dates among the sample data (for BOTH  "Bokad" and "Återkomster"), display the actual output of your script, and include a sheet showing the desired output.

@Tedinoz I have now updated the sheet. Did I run on the script and still the same problem. I have made it work before like this but now it doesn't, I'm confused so any ideas on what might be the problem is very helpful

You want to move data from given sheets to a master sheet where the date in the row is = Today. You also want to insert the data on the row after the last row of content in Column B.
One reason that the script was not working is that it used the Sheet: appendRow command = "Appends a row to the bottom of the current data region in the sheet." So this is inconsistent with appending to the bottom of Colmn B.

function MoveAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSh = ss.getSheetByName("Pipe");
  var sheets = ["Resting","Bokad","Återkomster"], sourceSh,dateCell;
  var dateCol = [];
  dateCol["Resting"] = 20;
  dateCol["Bokad"] = 15;
  dateCol["Återkomster"] = 14; 

  // get the last row of Colmn B on Pipe
  var bVals = targetSh.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var bLast = bVals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBG: Last Row B  = "+bLast+", next row = "+(+bLast+1))
  var lrTarget = bLast
 
  for (var sheetName of sheets)
  {
    sourceSh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    // Logger.log("DEBG: the sheet = "+sheetName)
    sheetData = sourceSh.getDataRange().getValues();

    // Check all values from your "Flight Schedule" sheet
    for(i = sheetData.length-1; i>= 0; i--){
      // Check if the value is a valid date
      dateCell = sheetData[i][dateCol[sheetName]-1];
      if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
        // Logger.log("i:"+i+", datecell: "+dateCell+" is a valid date")
        var today = new Date();
        var test = new Date(dateCell);
        // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
        if (sameDay(test, today)) {
          // Logger.log("DEBG: the date = TodaY")
          var targetRange = targetSh.getRange(+lrTarget+1,2,1,sheetData[i].length)
          // Logger.log("DEBG: The range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())
          var targetData = [sheetData[i]]
          targetRange.setValues(targetData)
          sourceSh.deleteRow(i+1);
          lrTarget = lrTarget+1
        }
        else{
          //Logger.log("DEBG: date <> TodaY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Hat-tip Iamblichus
*  Title: Check if in cell Today's date then continue 
*/ URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876898/1330560

function sameDay(d1, d2) {
  return d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
         d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
         d1.getDate() === d2.getDate();
}


BEFORE

Bokad

Återkomster

Pipe



AFTER

Bokad

Återkomster

Pipe


