# Matching a date on a calendar to another field

Tags: date, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok, I have a calendar on my page and each day is a formatted version of that date, eg.

```
Jan 2021
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
etc..
```

so the 1 cell will contain 1/1/2021 (but formatted to just show '1' [d])
I also have a cell (K5) on that page for a user to enter a date eg:[1/1/2021]

What i'd like is a script that changes the border colour of the day in the calendar if it matches the user entry cell.

The code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var date = sheet.getRange("K5").getValue();
if (e.range.getValue()== date) {
e.range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.solid); }
};
```

This doesn't work and I can't think of a way of having the code work for every cell of the calendar (there are 2 years worth so over 1000 cells).
It doesn't need to be onEdit, i was just testing to see if the actual setBorder function worked (which it does)
Also, I cant use conditional formatting as I've already used that to change to bg and font colours for something else (and there's no option to change boarder colour anyway)

I've made a mini version with just Jan if you'd like to have a look and see what you can do:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oV4lE8cQB-e2bVc_HgiGM31ivk3uHxPcqsSdLdCxsmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add at least just one more month (maybe two) so i can get a sense of whether there's a pattern to where the calendars are on the sheet?  Make sure it matches the real thing.

Comment: Haha, hope you're ready for this, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative to looking for all the dates would be to use a formula to show the dates and their addresses in a different sheet.  This formula will output a series of dates and their addresses for your holidays.  It can then be read with an onEdit() script to put borders on the correct addresses:

Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(N(Calendar!E9:AY)&"|"&ROW(Calendar!E9:AY)&"|"&COLUMN(Calendar!E9:AY)&"|"&LEN(TO_TEXT(Calendar!E9:AY))),"|",0,0),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4<3 and ("&TEXTJOIN(" or",TRUE," Col1="&FILTER(Calendar!BE28:BE100,Calendar!BE28:BE100<>""))&")")))
```

Script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  holidayBorders(e);
}

function holidayBorders(e){
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.value && sheet.getName()=='Calendar' && e.range.getColumn()==57 && e.range.getRow() >= 28){
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    var datasheet = e.source.getSheetByName('DATA');
    var rcs = datasheet.getRange('AQ3:AR').getValues().filter(e=> e[0]);

    for (let i=0;i<rcs.length;i++){
      sheet.getRange(rcs[i][0],rcs[i][1]).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.solid);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic solution @MattKing it's working great.
I was wondering how hard it would be to set the colour of any dates not in the list back to black. At the moment, dates keep their red border once the date is removed.

Comment: @JoeW i added a line of code that clears ALL the borders before looping through the holidays and marking them red.  I also took off the condition that a date be ADDED in order for the onedit to run.  That way clearing a date will also run the function.

Comment: Amazing, you're a genius! Seems to be working perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

- Get all values in your range, using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Iterate through all values in the resulting 2D array.
- For each value, check if (1) the value is a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (for example, using [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)) and whether the two dates are from the same day (for example, doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855166/how-to-tell-if-two-dates-are-in-the-same-day)).
- If both conditions are met, set the border.

#### Code snippet:

```
function setBorders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var date = sheet.getRange("K5").getValue();
  var firstRow = 7;
  var firstCol = 5;
  var data = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - firstCol + 1).getValues();  
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.forEach((value, j) => {
      if (value instanceof Date && sameDay(date, value)) {
        sheet.getRange(i + firstRow, j + firstCol).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.solid);
      }
    });
  })
}

function sameDay(date1, date2) {
  return date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
  date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
  date1.getDate() === date2.getDate();
}
```