# Why doesn't this function replace the existing value in the associative array - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, associative-array

I've made sure to import my interface:

```
import { DayMoodModel } from '../objectModels/dayMood';
```

I initialized the array of objects with some test data (the date property has the type Date, in case you're wondering):

```
  moodsAssigned: DayMoodModel[] = [
    { 
      date: this.today,
      mood: 'great'
    }
  ]
```

This is the function in question:

```
  addMood(moodName: string) {
    let obj: DayMoodModel = { date: this.currentDay, mood: moodName };
    for(let i = 0; i < this.moodsAssigned.length; i++) {
      if(this.moodsAssigned[i].date == this.currentDay) {
        this.moodsAssigned[i].mood = moodName;
      }
      else if(i == this.moodsAssigned.length - 1 && this.moodsAssigned[i].date != this.currentDay) {
        this.moodsAssigned.push(obj);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.moodsAssigned);
  }
```

When called, on a date that's already in the array of objects, it acts like that data isn't already in there for that date. I'll include a photo of the console log at the bottom of the post. In this test I called the function on the date that is already in the array, expecting it to replace the 'mood' value with the new mood, but it just added a new object to the array.

I've gone over this code multiple times, logging out variables at key places to ensure it's reading everything correctly. I don't know what's wrong with the logic..

[picture of the array logged to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td0kj.jpg)

Comment: In the attached screenshot, `moodsAssigned[0].date` is `Jan. 30, 2022 03:44:44` but `moodsAssigned[1].date`, the date of the new mood I assume you're trying to insert, has a value of `Jan. 30, 2022 00:00:00`. Do you only need for the date portion to match? Is the time portion is irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to compare two complex objects, yet you only care about the day, month, and year. Just a straight `==` isn't going to work.

Here is a proper comparison function from another question: [How to tell if two dates are in the same day or in the same hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855166/how-to-tell-if-two-dates-are-in-the-same-day-or-in-the-same-hour)

```js
function sameDay(d1, d2) {
  return d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
    d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
    d1.getDate() === d2.getDate();
}
```

However, if you don't want duplicates, instead of brute-force searching an array you can utilize ISO strings (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS) as keys in a `Map`. You can just take the first 10 characters if you don't care about the timestamp.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  today = this.getISO(new Date());
  moodsAssigned = new Map<string, string>([
    [this.today, 'great'],
  ]);

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getISO(date: Date) {
    return date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }

  addMood(moodName: string) {
    this.moodsAssigned.set(this.today, moodName);
  }
}
```

You can also convert an ISO string back into a `Date` object with the `Date` constructor - both YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS and YYYY-MM-DD work.

```js
const today = new Date("2022-01-30")
```